# Querying SQLite in Java - lightweight?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I need to execute one query in my program on a SQLite database. If I use the sqlite jdbc it is 3,5 Mb large. Is there no other simple solution for executing just one select query without needing a dependency that is so huge.

Comment: These days 3.5 MB isn't that much.  If you don't want to use such a library, you could write your own if the requirement is simple.  BTW `Mb` is mega-bit. `MB` is mega-byte.

Comment: What is the select queuey?  Could you writing it in Java using a plain  collection or read it from a file?

Comment: If you're on Mac OS / Linux you can 'call' the builtin CLI interface to execute simple select query parsing the result. I do agree with Peter that 3,5 MB is not so much, unless you're targeting very peculiar architectures.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It is basically a `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column3 LIKE xy`. I have a sqlite file given, so I need to query that. I guess I could parse it somehow, but it would be preferable to have a library that can do that for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [SQLJet](http://sqljet.com/) if you don't need to have full JDBC compliance. JAR is about 760Kb. And yes, technically, the library doesn't provide a SQL engine, it's an API which allows to select and fetch records from a sqlite database. Depending on your needs current and future it may or may not be suitable for you. I successfully use it inone small project to load records from a ~2.6GB sqlite DB and process them as needed.